# How to disable all "please rate our app" dialogues?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, root-access, xposed-framework, app-ratings

I use a lot of different apps, and many of them prompt me to rate them in the Play Store. Some of them don't have a "never" button, so they keep bugging me. Some of them don't realize it even if I've rated them, so they keep asking me to rate them after I've actually rated them. Also, I want to rate apps on my own initiative, I don't like such reminders.

Is there a way to block/disable/hide all such "please rate this app" prompts systemwide?

For example, it could be an Xposed module that looks for dialogues with buttons leading to rating in the Play Store and then blocks/hides those dialogues.

I have Xposed Framework and root access.

Comment: theoretically possible, but I highly doubt anyone got bothered enough to implement this. btw what apps do you have in mind? I can't remember when I saw this last time really.

Comment: @SargeBorsch Which apps, you mean?

Comment: the apps which show the annoying dialogs

Comment: @SargeBorsch Dozens of my apps do that.

Comment: maybe you could just find less annoying alternatives for them

Comment: @SargeBorsch It's not **that** annoying. I'm not willing to switch to a less preferable app just to avoid the dialogue.

Comment: then I would suggest reporting this as bug to the app developer(s), sometimes it does work.

Comment: @SargeBorsch I don't care that much, I don't want to contact dozens of developers. Also, I also want to block the ones that do disappear after I rate.

Comment: Mention it in your comments when you rate the app less than 5 stars to encourage the developers to fix it.

Comment: @TomG Yeah, I've done that before actually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Is there a way to block/disable/hide all such "please rate this app" prompts systemwide?*

[Apparently not possible](https://m.reddit.com/r/xposed/comments/4v942d/request_never_get_asked_to_rate_an_app_again/) as you can see from the same question answered on reddit by an Xposed module developer :

> There is no global rating dialog class that you could hook into, every app creates a standard dialog and adds their own contents to it, so you would have to decompile, analyze and hook every app separately.

Perhaps a developer here could add more by way of explanation, as to why it is not possible to employ a technique / tool that works across the board in disabling *rating* popups

Comment: Thanks for accepting but I was hoping for a more detailed explanation from the developers who frequent the site.

Comment: I had a problem with this persistent pop up and app support replied. It helped so adding it here 
 Quote in the programs folder of Snap ( app name) you will find a file called settings.txt. Please send that file, so we can check it. Probably in this file it states *rateAskAgain=true* but it needs to be
*rateAskAgain=false* unquote